# Ajax image grabber

Tags: php, image, jquery

I need an image grabber.  By that I mean a Digg like image grabber that can search other pages (including youtube, normal websites, economist,...whatever), get the images that are of decent sizes and if I select it, I can upload it to my server.

Does anyone know of a plugin for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any off-the-shelf library. But I once needed a quick way to retrieve the "main image" off a page. My best guess was to just get the largest in file size. I was using the PHP [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library for easy access to the site's `<img>` tags.

Now, here's the main part of the code, that returns the URL of the biggest image file for a given page.

Hope you can build on that.

```
// Load the remote document
$html = file_get_html($url);

$largest_file_size=0;
$largest_file_url='';

// Go through all images of that page
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
    // Helper function to make absolute URLs from relative
    $img_url=$this->InternetCombineUrl($url,$element->src);
    // Try to get image file size info from header:
    $header=array_change_key_case(get_headers($img_url, 1));
    // Only continue if "200 OK" directly or after first redirect:
    if($header[0]=='HTTP/1.1 200 OK' || @$header[1]=='HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
        if(!empty($header['content-length'])){
            // If we were redirected, the second entry is the one.
            // See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#84130
            if(!empty($header['content-length'][1])){
                $header['content-length']=$header['content-length'][1];
            }
            if($header['content-length']>$largest_file_size){
            $largest_file_size=$header['content-length'];
            $largest_file_url=$img_url;
            }
        }else{ 
            // If no content-length-header is sent, we need to download the image to check the size
            $tmp_filename=sha1($img_url);
            $content = file_get_contents($img_url);
            $handle = fopen(TMP.$tmp_filename, "w");
            fwrite($handle, $content);
            fclose($handle);
            $filesize=filesize(TMP.$tmp_filename);
            if($filesize>$largest_file_size){
            $largest_file_size=$filesize;
            $largest_file_url=$img_url;
            unlink(TMP.$tmp_filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
return $largest_file_url;
```

Comment: I'll have a look at it.  Thanks.